# Is self password reset allowed with free Azure AD?I

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have free Azure AD and when I go to the password reset setting in he Azur  portal, it says I need to upgrade to premium to try the feature.

If I try to use the password reset page to change a user password (without upgrading) it tells me there is an error and administrator needs to set password reset policy.

However, I have seen documentations where it says this is possible. Here is a link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/active-directory/.

I was wondering if I am missing something here, especially after looking at the table in the link above where it says I should be able to reset password with free Azure AD.

Comment: This action needs Global Administrator privileges.  Do have this role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With free Azure AD, you have the feature 'Self-Service Password **Change** for cloud users'.

If you want to use the feature 'Self-Service Password **Reset** for cloud users'. You need to upgrade to premium.

They are different features.